# Selecting a local file via HTML5 input and sending it via websocket to nodejs server

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, file-upload, websocket

this might be an easy question but I'm really stuck with this at the moment.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<form id="fileButtons">
    <input name="file" type="file" accept="text/*">
    <button id="uploadBtn" name="upload" type="button">
        <span><b>Upload</b></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

The user should select a file from his local drive via the input with type="file". After this, he should be able to upload the file by clicking the button with id="uploadBtn". So in my JavaScript there has to be something like this:

```
$(uploadBtn).click(function ()
{
    ws.send("some file I have had selected before");
});
```

So now I have no idea how i can access the selected file and push it to the server. I'll be thankful for any help!

Comment: The WebSockets protocol is neither a good nor a safe way to transfer files, you should better use another technique and maybe just use a POST. But technically it is possible for smaller files: http://mustafaakin.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/introducing-websocket-file-transfer/

Comment: I'm using node.js. I'm also open to implement this task with a POST method but I'm newbie on client/server file exchange and searching the internet gives me thousands of possibilities where chosing the right one seems to be impossible at the first look.. :/